# Finding highest normal form of a relation of database

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf, third-normal-form

What is the highest normal form of relation R(A,B,C,D), given FDs **A--> B; CD--> B; A--> CD; CD--> A** ? **Please** not only give the answer but also give a **step by step approach** to solve a problem of this kind.

Comment: This is homework, isn't it? - What have you tried so far?

Comment: "step by step approach" 1.Go through some books. 2.Try it yourself. 3.Ask a question which shows your effort.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy; with due respect I'd like to tell you , that I've been working on this topic from 3 days and I feel almost stuck in this confusion. As far as simple functional dependencies are concerned, I don't find any difficulty but when functional dependencies goes topsy-turvy, It feels like hell. I am undergoing training in infosys, and I've limited time to read each n every book  n look for all material.

Comment: @RubbalBhusri: His point is that your question might show frustration, but it doesn't show your effort. As far as the reader can tell, you might have copied that question straight from a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The candidate keys are A and CD, which you can determine by inspection in this case. (It's a simple problem; you can determine the closures in your head.) A->B, A->CD; that's all the attributes. CD->A, CD->B; again, that's all the attributes.

Since all the arrows are arrows out of candidate keys, it's in at least BCNF. (That's the informal definition of BCNF.)

All database textbooks include at least one algorithm for determining all the candidate keys, and for normalizing a set of relations to 5NF. If you don't have one, Maier's [*The Theory of Relational Databases*](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~maier/TheoryBook/TRD.html) is available free a the author's faculty web site.

Comment: So, a key becomes candidate key when it uniquely identifies all rest of the keys. But I've a problem in which, this theory doesn't seem to apply. The relation R(X,Y,Z,L) The FDs are: **X->YZL; XL-> YZ; ZL->XL** What is the HNF here acc. to you ? and How ?

Comment: A candidate key determines all the rest of the attributes. In R(X,Y,Z,L), what are the candidate keys?

Comment: **X** is determining all rest of the attributes, **XL** also determines rest of the attributes; **ZL** also determines rest of the attributes, therefore **X, XL, ZL** are the candidate keys.

Comment: XL isn't a candidate key, because X *by itself* is a candidate key. XL is reducible; candidate keys are irreducible. XL->YZ reduces to X->YZ, which is redundant. (Because X->YZL is given.)

Comment: So, after finding the candidate keys, we have to select one of them as our primary key, and then see, if the relation is in 2NF and 3NF. Isn't it ?

Comment: You don't have to select a primary key. In the relational model, all candidate keys are created equal. Normal forms have to take every candidate key into account. If you're just trying to determine whether a relation is in BCNF, you don't have to think about 2NF or 3NF. BCNF is now defined in terms of candidate keys, not in terms of lower normal forms.

Comment: I am concerned only upto 3NF,coz the scope of my studies limits only to 3NF. In the problem given above, since **X** determines rest of the attributes, and no attribute depends on the partial key(coz, partial of **X** isn't possible), which makes the relation in 2NF. And no attribute depends transitively on **X**, which makes this relation in 3NF. Isn't it ?

Comment: Partial of LZ is possible. You have to consider *every* candidate key.

Comment: Partial of LZ is either L or Z, but there is not any attribute that depends specifically on L or Z alone. Therefore , considering LZ for finding HNF can be ruled out. Isn't it so ?

Comment: *"Therefore , considering LZ for finding HNF can be ruled out."* No. Every time you evaluate the normal form of a relation, you evaluate it with respect to *every* candidate key. If you ask, "Is R in 3NF?", you have to look at every candidate key. If you ask, "Is R in BCNF?", you have to look at every candidate key. Etc.

Comment: I got your point. but Do you find any attribute that depends on partial of LZ and do u find any attribute that transitively depends on LZ ?

Comment: No, there aren't any in R(XYZL).

Comment: Thank u so much for ur kind help. Your answers were very informative.

Comment: You're welcome. On StackOverflow, we express thanks by upvoting good answers and accepting the best answers.